# Low TTL with Leveled Compaction, should I reduce gc_grace_seconds to improve read performance without impacting delete replication?

Tags: java, cassandra, database, nosql

**Low TTL with Leveled Compaction, should I reduce gc_grace_seconds to improve read performance?**

**Scenario:**
Cassandra Table to cache an external db values - read performance needs to be good (less than 100ms)
TTL = 4 hrs at row level
Functional full table refresh (delete and then lazy load) every 6 hrs
If I keep gc_grace_seconds at default value of **10 days**, I can potentially have 60 rows with tombstones for every live row. This will affect read performance. Or not?

Is reducing gc_grace_seconds to say **1 day** a safe enough value to allow delete replication across nodes? Given that even if a node is out of tier for some issue, it should be brought back in less than a day. Will this improve read performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can potentially have 60 rows with tombstones for every live row. This will affect read performance. Or not?

Yes, it will definitely affect your read performance.  At a data/tombstone ratio of 1:60, you'll be asking Cassandra to weed through 60 deletes for every good row.  If you have a lot of records, it will probably perform pretty terribly.

> Is reducing gc_grace_seconds to say 1 day a safe enough value to allow delete replication across nodes? Given that even if a node is out of tier for some issue, it should be brought back in less than a day. Will this improve read performance?

This should improve your read performance significantly.  But the drawback, is that if you have a node drop out of the cluster, you then only have 1 day to get it back in before it has no idea about the delete.  But even if you miss it, you should be able to get your node back to a consistent state by running a `nodetool repair`.  Otherwise you'll run the possible risk of [deleted data re-appearing](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the confirmation. Apart from this, I also have a use case for a full table purge. One option I have at hand is to run a truncate(column family) cql. I can automate truncate and flush after that. Is this a recommended approach for such a table?

Comment: So even when using Leveled Compaction, should I reduce gc_grace_seconds to improve read performance without impacting delete replication?

Comment: You could check out https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7019?focusedCommentId=15346911&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-15346911 nodetool garbage collect